# Por que en c# al usar async/await en una aplicacion de consola funciona diferente que en una aplicacion de windows froms

Tags: c#, hilos, async

Cuando uso async y await en consola y escritorio, no se obtienen resultados iguales y queria saber por que pasa esto.

(Estuve usando "Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId" para controlar en que hilo se ejecuta cada linea)

Este es el codigo que estuve probando en la aplicacion de consola.
En la aplicacion de windows form es igual pero en vez ejecutar Prueba desde el Main, lo ejecuto desde un boton: "private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Main-Inicia: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Prueba();
    Debug.WriteLine("Main-Prueba-luego: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

private static async Task<int> DelayAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("delay1: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Debug.WriteLine("termino Delay1: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Debug.WriteLine("termino Delay2: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return 1;
    }

    public static async void Prueba()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("prueba: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var delayTask = DelayAsync(); 
        Debug.WriteLine("prueba-luego: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var x = await delayTask;
        Debug.WriteLine("termino Prueba: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

Pero al ejecutar ambos obtengo resultados diferentes:

```
Consola:
--------
Main-Inicia: 1
prueba: 1
delay1: 1
'LectorXml.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: LectorXml.exe): 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
prueba-luego: 1
Main-Prueba-luego: 1
termino Delay1: 5
'LectorXml.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: LectorXml.exe): 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode' cargado. 
termino Delay2: 5
termino Prueba: 5
El subproceso 0x4a6c terminó con código 0 (0x0).

Interfaz:
---------
Main-Inicia: 1
prueba: 1
delay1: 1
'app.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: app.exe): 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
prueba-luego: 1
Main-Prueba-luego: 1
termino Delay1: 1
termino Delay2: 1
termino Prueba: 1
El subproceso 0x4ba8 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

---

Ahora, si reemplazo esta linea por esta otra en el mismo sitio:

```
var x=delayTask.Result;
//var x = await delayTask;
```

En el caso de la aplicacion de windows forms, este se cuelga mientras la consola no y se obtienen estos resultados

```
Consola:
-------
prueba: 1
delay1: 1
'LectorXml.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: LectorXml.exe): 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
prueba-luego: 1
termino Delay1: 5
termino Delay2: 5
termino Prueba: 1
Main-Prueba-luego: 1
'LectorXml.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: LectorXml.exe): 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode' cargado. 
El subproceso 0x45dc terminó con código 0 (0x0).

Interfaz:
---------
prueba: 1
delay1: 1
'app.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: app.exe): 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
prueba-luego: 1
El subproceso 0x4d10 terminó con código 0 (0x0). --> aqui se cuelga
```

Parece que en windows forms solo usase un hilo ¿Por que sucede esto?

¿Que deberia hacer si lo que quiero es que en una aplicacion windows forms, al presionar un boton siga el flujo como en la aplicacion de consola pero sin que se cuelgue y que se ejecute el metodo Prueba() inmediatamente en paralelo en un hilo separado, sabiendo que Prueba llamara a una tarea asincrona como DelayAsync? Es decir, que mi resultado sea algo asi:

```
Interfaz:
--------
Main-Inicia: 1
prueba: 2            --> deben ejecutarse en paralelo inmediatamente
Main-Prueba-luego: 1 --> deben ejecutarse en paralelo inmediatamente
delay1: 2
prueba-luego: 2
termino Delay1: 3
termino Delay2: 3
termino Prueba: 2
```

Comment: Si, tu thread en winforms es uno solo, y por eso parece que se cuelga. deberias mirar este video, donde explican todo esto que preguntas. La explicacion es larga o demasiado corta y te deja con ganas. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2HDDKq4d3c&t=5586s